# Error : relation "OutboxState" does not exist

Tags: .net, postgresql, rabbitmq, masstransit

Below is my Program.cs setup :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AuctionDbContext>(opt =>
{
    opt.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddEntityFrameworkOutbox<AuctionDbContext>(o =>
    {
        o.QueryDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

        o.UsePostgres();
        o.UseBusOutbox();
    });

    x.AddConsumersFromNamespaceContaining<AuctionCreatedFaultConsumer>();

    x.SetEndpointNameFormatter(new KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter("auction", false));

    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.UseRetry(r =>
        {
            r.Handle<RabbitMqConnectionException>();
            r.Interval(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        });

        cfg.Host(builder.Configuration["RabbitMq:Host"], "/", host =>
        {
            host.Username(builder.Configuration.GetValue("RabbitMq:Username", "guest"));
            host.Password(builder.Configuration.GetValue("RabbitMq:Password", "guest"));
        });

        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = builder.Configuration["IdentityServiceUrl"];
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = false;
        options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "username";
    });
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuctionRepository, AuctionRepository>();
builder.Services.AddGrpc();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapGrpcService<GrpcAuctionService>();

var retryPolicy = Policy
    .Handle<NpgsqlException>()
    .WaitAndRetry(5, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

retryPolicy.ExecuteAndCapture(() => DbInitializer.InitDb(app));

app.Run();
```

On starting the application, I am getting the below error.

```
fail: MassTransit.EntityFrameworkCoreIntegration.BusOutboxDeliveryService[0]
      ProcessMessageBatch faulted
      Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P01: relation "OutboxState" does not exist

Exception data:
  Severity: ERROR
  SqlState: 42P01
  MessageText: relation "OutboxState" does not exist
  Position: 128
  File: parse_relation.c
  Line: 1392
  Routine: parserOpenTable
```

I am using RabbitMQ with MassTransit and PostGres database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it, The problem was in the EntityFramework Migration. I did not add migration for the below MassTransit Tables.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.AddInboxStateEntity();
        modelBuilder.AddOutboxMessageEntity();
        modelBuilder.AddOutboxStateEntity();
    }
```